# How to keep NSPanel within NSScreen visibleframe always

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, positioning, nswindow

I have one floating NSPanel in my app, which user can move using mouse. I want my NSPanel to always visible within main screen. I want code to reposition my NSPanel with its original width and height within screen border in all the sides.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Subclass NSPanel and override the frame-relative methods. *setFrameOrigin:*, *setFrame:display:* and maybe others (see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to find out all the methods). There is also promising `- (NSRect)constrainFrameRect:(NSRect)frameRect toScreen:(NSScreen *)screen` method.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the documentation and let you know.

Comment: I did such subclass for my needs. The task wasn't identical to your, but in general they are similar: I wanted to constraint panel movements and sizing with mu rules. Overriding setFrameOrigin: and SetFrame:display: did the trick for me. Unfortunately, the class is pretty specific and complicated, so there is no point in publishing the code.

Comment: Thanks, I am still trying to make such subclass , but didn't get success yet.